# How to configure RabbitMQ connection with spring-rabbit?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm following [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#initial) to learn how to use `spring-rabbit` with RabbitMQ. However in this guide, the RabbitMQ configuration is as default(localhost server and with credential as guest/guest). What should I do if I want to connect to an remote RabbitMQ with ip address and credential? I don't know where to set these information in my application.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The application for that guide is a Spring Boot Application.

Add a file `application.properties` to `src/main/resources`.

You can then configure rabbitmq properties according to the [Spring Boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties) - scroll down to the rabbitmq properties...

```
...
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost # RabbitMQ host.
...
spring.rabbitmq.password= # Login to authenticate against the broker.
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672 # RabbitMQ port.
...
spring.rabbitmq.username= # Login user to authenticate to the broker.
...
```

To connect to a cluster, use

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses= # Comma-separated list of addresses to which the client should connect.
```

e.g. `server1:5672,server2:5672`.

If you don't want to use boot auto configuration, declare a `CachingConnectionFactory` `@Bean` yourself and configure it as desired.

Comment: It's weird, I added these properties into `application.properties` as you suggested. However, these properties seems haven't been loaded into the running application. Anything I missed?

Comment: I just downloaded the guide, added `application.properties` to `src/main/resources` for the `complete` version and pointed it to a remote rabbitmq instance and it worked just fine - I see the queue created on the rabbit instance and the output messages. How are you running the guide?

Comment: My bad, sorry, your solution works like a charm. It didn't work here because I added `@Bean MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) { return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");}` in my configuration class.

Comment: How do you achieve this programatically?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/) and [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples). It's better to ask a completely new question rather than asking a new question in a comment on an old one.

Comment: @GaryRussell with spring boot I am using application.yml and configured all ssl properties from Appendix A except ssl algorithm. In this case my application always tries PLAIN authentication. I know that defining EXTERNAL sasl config can resolve it, I am looking for any configuration I need to make to do that without defining any beans. Can I add any property in application yml and achieve it?

Comment: As I stated above; you must not ask new questions in a comment on a very old answer; ask a new question showing your current configuration and exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for quick response - I have asked a new question here request your help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752686/spring-rmq-listener-always-use-plain-auth-even-after-configuring-ssl-properties

Comment: Hi! 
Do you know how can I connect a kubernetes rabbitmq cluster using your the addresses properties? Or any approach. Currently I've tried bellow approach but no success. The rabbitmq-service is of loadbalancer type.
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=http://rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-service:5672,http://rabbitmq-1.rabbitmq-service:5672

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments on 3 year old answers; I am not a k8s expert; people from the Kubernetes community won't see it; ask a new question instead, tagged with the relevant technologies. Why do you have `http:` in there?